# symfony 1.4 routing

Tags: symfony-1.4

I'm having a problem with my routing, so any help would be much appreciated?

How would I set up a routing rule for the following:

```
 /MyUrl/edit/
 /MyUrl/edit/[something]
```

and the [something] is sent over as a variable.

I'm using symfony 1.4 doing this in propel.

Thanks

Comment: I hope `MyUrl` is module and `edit` is method in action class. Is it correct assumption? or `MyUrl` is domain, `edit` is module with `index` as default method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I recommend you read the tutorial** - [**JOBEET**](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/05)

```
yourFirstRout:  
  url:   /yourFirstRout/edit
  param: { module: yourModule, action: edit }

yourSecondRout:  
  url:   /yourSecondRout/edit/:something
  param: { module: yourModule, action: editEntry }
```

**something** - is a parameter, for example id. In  action **editEntry**, you can get this parameter from **request** :

```
$something = $request->getParameter('something');
```

And then you can search in DB entry by this parameter.